# Cannot install Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion ze1202 with 256MB RAM

Tags: installation, live-cd

I want to install Ubuntu on an HP Pavilion ze1202 with 256MB RAM but I can't install. Any help?

I tried installing it twice already and either its RAM is too slow but it shows the installation page. I choose the option "Install Ubuntu"  but it starts and just shows the desktop background and after a long time it shows the top bar with some things.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using the alternate installer. You can download the alternate install cd from here:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/

The installer will be text based and should run fine on a computer with those resources. Since you have such little ram, I would also recommend using a flavor such as lubuntu or xubuntu instead of ubuntu itself. Using a lighter weight distro will work better for your limited hardware.

Reference this wiki page for even more options:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/LowMemorySystems

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend Lubuntu for this machine, one of the absolute lightest 'buntu distributions, and it now has official status:  http://lubuntu.net/

I've done tests and the graphical installer works on a machine with 256Mb of RAM, however there needs to be a swap partition available on the hard drive for it to use.  This means setting the partitions up with something like the Gparted LiveCD first.  If this sounds a bit hard for you at this stage, just download the alternate installer and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

## Install Xubuntu!

[Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org) is a friend of Ubuntu which is specially designed for old computers. It comes with Xfce desktop. I don't think you can run Unity Desktop in Ubuntu, properly with a 256MB RAM.